# Why does % Window.width with (self.object.uvpos[0] + time) in clock_interval make moving textures work correctly in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm doing a tutorial about making a game, and still in the background period, making moving textures. But I just wonder why the wrapped problem fixed by %Window.width in the line `self.cloud_texture.uvpos =  {(self.cloud_texture.uvpos[0] + time_passed)%Window.width ,self.cloud_texture.uvpos[1]}`

I see no problem when I just do `self.cloud_texture.uvpos[0] + time_passed` only, but the result told me the difference when it's changing the `self.cloud_texture.uvpos[1]` too, and starting to get some glitch when resizing window after few seconds.

Can someone give me an explanation so I can apply it to my other apps?

**.py file**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window

class Background(Widget):
    cloud_texture = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        
        #create texture
        self.cloud_texture = Image(source="assets/cloud.png").texture
        self.cloud_texture.wrap = "repeat"
        self.cloud_texture.uvsize = {Window.width / self.cloud_texture.width, -1}
    
    def scroll_textures(self,time_passed):
        self.cloud_texture.uvpos =  {(self.cloud_texture.uvpos[0] + time_passed)%Window.width ,self.cloud_texture.uvpos[1]}
        texture = self.property("cloud_texture")
        texture.dispatch(self)
        
from kivy.clock import Clock

class MainApp(App):
    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.root.ids.background.scroll_textures, 1/60)
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

**.kv file**

```
FloatLayout:
    Background:
        id: background
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
                source: "assets/sky.png"
            Rectangle:
                size: self.width, 138
                pos: self.pos[0], self.pos[1] + self.height - 138
                texture: self.cloud_texture
```

You can find the images I'm using [here](https://github.com/Dirk-Sandberg/2DKivyGame/tree/master/2DGameTutorial_part1)